# Visual Studio 2013 dosen't recognize anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, mvvm-light, visual-studio-2013

I opened my WinRT (I'm using MVVMLight) project in Visual Studio 2013 this morning, and found out that all kind of types even system ones are not recognized saying `Cannot resolve symbol 'bool'` for example, <del>note that the solution builds, executes and works all fine !</del>

**C# :**

[image]

Even **XAML :**

[image]

I tried many things, closed and reopened the solution, cleared Resharper caches, I even restarted Visual Studio and the PC, but still the same problem, any solution to this problem ?

**Update 1** : I tried to Suspend/Resume Resharper from Tools>Options and even delete files from AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.0\SolutionCaches, and now Visual Studio causes errors too :

[image]

**Update 2** : I uninstalled/re-installed visual studio, and I still have the same problems

Comment: Have you tried `Suspend` and then `Resume` from `VS -> Tools -> Options -> ReSharper`?

Comment: No I didn't I'll try that

Comment: Disabling/updatin plugins like StyleCop in the Resharper options helps as well in some cases.

Comment: @Rohit Vats : Suspending it stops the problem, Resuming it resumes it again

Comment: Make sure you clear the cache `AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\SolutionCaches` before resuming it.

Comment: Try deleting the `.suo` file

Comment: @Rohit Vats : I tried that , when I resumed Resharper , I tried to run the application, I got 136 errors, now even VisualStudio isn't happy

Comment: @levelnis : Where can I find that file ??

Comment: yes @RohitVats lots of them, I've just updated my question

Comment: :( I also faced this issue few times back and performing steps like i suggested solved it for me. :(

Comment: It should be in the same directory as the solution file

Comment: @AymenDaoudi : Do you have any Xamarin products installed?

Comment: Yeah @Alexander I installed Xamarin just the night before

Comment: So, it is the reason of the issue. There are some compatibility problems for Xamarin/ReSharper http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-394695. As a possible workaround, mentioned in ticket: please select 'true' for 'Use msbuild to obtain project references' in Project Properties (Click on project name in Solution Explorer | Hit F4) for each project in the solution.

Comment: @Alexander I think it's the cause as you said, I just uninstalled all Xamarin components from my PC and VS2013 is now all fine, I ll reinstall it and take in consideration the workaround you gave me, please consider adding your comment as an answer to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have any Xamarin extensions for Visual Studio installed, it is a root of the problem. There are some [compatibility problems](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-394695).

As a possible workaround, you may try a workaround, mentioned in this ticket:

> Select 'true' for 'Use msbuild to obtain project references' in
>   Project Properties (Click on project name in Solution Explorer | Hit
>   F4) for each project in the solution.

At least, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can build the solution, but ReSharper marks your code in red - you can write the request [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP) and you will likely get a help.

If you can't build your project then it is not ReSharper's problem. Then we need to find out why your build is broken.

It seems that your project to assembly references are broken. 
To understand what's happening here with references during the build, go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build/Debug and set the verbosity to diagnostic. Then try to build your project and investigate the output windows in VS (or you can use MSBuild.exe from the command line instead). What you need to find in this large text block is "Resolve Assembly references" or "Expand SDK references" task. These tasks should obtain the valid paths to the assemblies your project depends on. Later on csc.exe should be executed with all these paths as parameters.
You can check whether the paths are correct, do they indicate to the existing binaries or not.

You can also create a new WinRT project template and check if it can build. If it cannot even for the clean project template then it is obviously a system problem, I suppose your platform sdk's are corrupted.

Hope this will help.